# How do I bridge a button from an application to a custom python toolbar application?

Tags: python, windows, button

How do I bridge a button from an application to a different application? This is hard to ask due to my lack of terminology but here is the example scenario. Lets say you have a play button on a website like Pandora.com and you want to take that play button and add it to your python program so that you can use your python program and be working in that but then click the play button in your program and it will press the play button on Pandora.com without physically changing tabs. What is this called and how would you even approach this in python?

Any direction you can point me in because this will be useful later with other tools, my goal is to make a custom tool bar that i can link everything together in a python application but I'm not even sure what this would be called perhaps button streaming?

A hacked way of doing it would be to track the packet that is sent when you play and pause and use python to send the raw packet to python that pauses and plays it. But there has to be a better way and I'm looking to do more of this like setting up a search bar and what not.

It would be most useful to explain if you can tell me where to start and what it is that I am trying to do so I can throughly research it.

(Os: windows 7)Thank you

Comment: You could create a browser extension and expose some sort of API with which you can work using Python.

Comment: Is there a work around because it seems pandora is up tight and does not have a current working API?

Comment: I meant an interface with the browser, not with Pandora. So you could execute JS code via Python to control the website.